# Java 8 Sort A Map By Key given an ordered set of keys

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I would like to sort a map in Java 8 using Stream by key but the order is defined in ordered set.

Key to order by:

```
LinkedHashSet<String> keysToOrderBy = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
keysToOrderBy.add("b");
keysToOrderBy.add("c");
keysToOrderBy.add("d");
keysToOrderBy.add("a");
keysToOrderBy.add("e");
```

The map:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new Map<String, Object>();
map.put("a",...);
map.put("b",...);
map.put("c",...);
```

The stream sort using parallel defaults:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> ordered = 
      map.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .parallel()
               .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                   Map.Entry::getKey,
                   Map.Entry::getValue, 
                   (v1, v2) -> v1,
                   LinkedHashMap::new
               ));
```

The order of the new Map should be:

```
"b"
"c"
"d"
"a"
"e"
```

I assume I have to use a custom comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use a custom comparator; you just iterate over the sorted elements instead of the unsorted elements.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> ordered = keysToOrderBy.stream()
    .filter(map::containsKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e -> e,
                map::get, 
                (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: By the way does parallel affect the order of iteration? Because I would like order to have order and make sure it's efficient. I might be sorting up to a few 100 keys. Maybe for 100 key straight iteration is ok I guess. But anywhere I can shave time is good.

Comment: For a few hundreds of keys, parallelizing it will be slower than just doing it sequentially in the first place.  You have to have much bigger data for parallelism to be worth it.  http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html has some advice on this.  Generally speaking, always assume parallelizing operations will make them _slower_ until you have done math and measurement to prove otherwise.

Comment: I believe parallelizing it will _work_, but even so it's more likely to hurt performance than to help.

Comment: I need to do it over a few 100 keys over a few 1000 maps. Still might not be big enough. I'll find out through testing...

Comment: In that case, parallelizing over the maps would probably be the best approach, without parallelizing over the entries.